# Deleting a row with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, `image` and `restaurant`.  I've set up a many-to-many relationship between them.

Here are the relevant parts of the table definitions:

```
images_assoc = Table('restaurant_image_assoc', Base.metadata,
        Column('restaurant', Integer(unsigned=True),
            ForeignKey('restaurant.id')),
        Column('image', Integer(unsigned=True),
            ForeignKey('image.id')))

class Image(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'image'
    id = Column(Integer(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    reports = Column(TinyInt, nullable=False, default=0)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now)

class Restaurant(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'restaurant'
    id = Column(Integer(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    images = relationship(Image, secondary=images_assoc)
```

I need to delete a row in `image`, but of course I need to delete all the rows in `restaurant_image_assoc` that point to it first.  How do I do this?

I tried this:

```
request.db.query(images_assoc)\
        .filter(images_assoc.c.image==image.id).delete()
request.db.delete(image)
request.db.commit()
```

Where `image` is the row I want to delete, but I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'class_'
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the delete-orphan cascade on the relationship between image and image_assoc? [see here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#unitofwork-cascades)

Comment: There is no relationship, and when I try to make one it starts shouting at me.  I've currently hacked something working together using raw SQL.  >.<

Comment: the specific error message here is that Query() doesn't work with a Table like that right now (query(images_assoc)...delete()).  Like other answers though, just manipulating Restaurant.images will automatically take care of rows in images_assoc - since it's "secondary", this is regardless of cascade settings.  that is, if you say restaurant.images.remove(some_image), then flush, that's all you need to delete the row in images_assoc.

Comment: Problem is when you have too many objects. SqlAlchemy throws tons of delete froms. In our case it's up to 55000k rows per object and we have about 2k objects. Our postgres is fast, but it takes ages to run 55k*2k = 110 millions of queries

Answer (score 0):

If you delete a row in image, you should get that image id. Then you can delete in your assoc table where image id == your image id.

Comment: I can't even do that.  I updated my post to show what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that SA does not track the relationship between Restaurant and the Image from the side of the Image, and therefore it "does not know" that there is a dependency. As soon as you configure the relationship from the other side, the respective rows in the association table will be also deleted automatically. In order to add the other side of the relationship it is enough to simply use the `backref`:

```
class Restaurant(Base):
    images = relationship(Image, secondary=images_assoc, backref="restaurants")
```

but you can also define those explicitly on each object (`back_populates` is required in this case):

```
class Image(Base):
    restaurants = relationship("Restaurant", secondary=images_assoc, back_populates="images")
class Restaurant(Base):
    images = relationship(Image, secondary=images_assoc, back_populates="restaurants")
```

But the latter is semantically the same as using `backref`.